# How to change Background Tint for all states?

Tags: java, android, colors

I would like to know how I can change background tint for all states.

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
            new int[] {android.R.attr.state_empty, reminderColor.getMeasuredState()}};
    int[] colors = new int[] {color};
    ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    reminderColor.setBackgroundTintList(myList);
```

Actually, with this code my ImageView just disappear. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I find the solution, I had to set default color with an empty state, now, it works and i have this code:

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
            new int[] {}};
    int[] colors = new int[] {color};
    ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    reminderColor.setBackgroundTintList(myList);
```